# Curl POST request fails

Tags: curl

Curl version installed on My system was :curl 7.35.0
I tried to run the  below command but it returned an errorcode 7:

```
outpt=0;

FUEL_TOKEN_JSON="$( /usr/bin/curl --noproxy '*' -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username":"","password":""},"tenantName":""}}' -e "http://IP:port/" -k -A 'Mozilla' "http://IP:port/keystone/v2.0/tokens" || :)" || outpt=$?

ErrorReceived:puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class ::keystone at /etc/puppet/modules/fuel/manifests/keystone.pp
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You should make your question more clear and understanding, see as well [how to ask a good question](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Comment: This is not a problem with curl, but with your Puppet class. Fix that.

Comment: @muru Perhaps that is better suited as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen from the output, the problem is *not* with curl, but with your Puppet class:

```
ErrorReceived:puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not find declared class ::keystone at /etc/puppet/modules/fuel/manifests/keystone.pp
```

Specifically, something's wrong with `/etc/puppet/modules/fuel/manifests/keystone.pp` on your Puppet server.